# Error when creating a stored procedure in MariaDB

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MariaDB, and I keep getting the error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 9

```html
DELIMITER $$
Create procedure patientcheck(IN hospitalcode int(11))
BEGIN 

Select Staff1.First_name, Staff1.Surname, Staff1.Dep1
From Patient1, Staff1, Staff_allocator
Where Patient1.PatientID1=Staff_allocator.PatientID1 and Staff1.StaffID1=Staff_allocator.StaffID1
And Patient1.PatientID1=hospitalcode 

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: apologies for the horrendous formatting, first time properly programming in this language

Comment: Missing semicolon before the END$$ to terminate the select statement.

Comment: nope, gives me another error on that line "Unexpected character. (near ;)

Comment: I tested it on MySQL 8.0, and it works fine. There is no error once the missing semicolon is restored. So I assume either the problem is specific to MariaDB, or else you are making some other mistake. The error you reported is clearly from MariaDB, not MySQL, so I edited to make it clear you are using MariaDB.

Comment: I think it will be ideal to mention im using phpmyadmin^. maybe this will affect my results?

Comment: the light across the bridge- out of frustration, I cut all my code and just rewrote it line by line as-is. and finally it decided to run even with the unexpected character error. hurray!

Answer (score 0):

im not sure how or why my issue was solved, but after rewriting my code character by character, even without changing anything ( and re adding the ";"), the code finally ran. (ive been told that phpmyadmin is very buggy and unstable and is prone to silly issues like this)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of your select statement. You changed the delimiter to $$, but you still need to add the semicolon to the end of the query. I ran this exact code on a MariaDB instance with the semicolon added and it ran without error.

Comment: perhaps it is related to my version? I cannot run it with the semicolon at the end as stated before, I get an "unexpected character" error

Comment: I think it will be ideal to mention im using phpmyadmin^

Comment: Missing semicolon is just a typo. Please do not answer a question if you think it was caused by a typo, just leave a comment to that effect and flag / vote the question for closure. If you do not have enough reputation to comment, then leave the question as is. Reason: typo is an explicit close reason.